# Set maxLength attribute onInit using Angular

Tags: html, angular, kendo-ui

I have a kendo-chat component that comes with an input inside it. So the input element does not display on my html file. I want to set the maxLength for that input element, dynamically. This is my progress so far,

```
  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const inp = this.document.getElementsByClassName('k-input');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(inp, 'maxLength', '5');
  }
```

Can somebody help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ngOnInit` hook might be too soon to access a DOM element. Try to do it in the `ngAfterViewInit` hook. BTW what is the error you get now?

Comment: You shouldn't use document properties in agular apps. You can solve in html as binding or you can solve with viewChild or you can solve with ngClass . Anyway. getElementsByClassName returns more than one element you can't say directly change if there are more than one elmement you need loop or only one add [0] at the end to take first one

Comment: Does the `maxLength` you want to dynamically set come from a finite set of possibilities or is it a wide range of possible values?

Comment: @pc_coder Using `ViewChild` wouldn't work since the input element is inside the KendoChat component which is a child of OP's component. I agree that using `getElementsByClassName()` isn't recommended in an Angular app in general. If OP wants to use it anyway, despite it being a bad idea, it's better to get the specific kendo-chat element, for instance using `ViewChild`, and then searching for the specific input element inside it.